# Suggestion on the new description in the tag menu

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag menu currently looks like this:

[image]

I would rather write that as one of the following:

- at least one tag (such as limits, differential-equations, real-analysis), max 5 tags.
- at least one tag, such as (limits), (differential-equations), (real-analysis), max 5 tags.
- at least one tag, such as limits, differential-equations, real-analysis, max 5 tags.

Also, consider writing **or** instead of the last comma in the list.

I think that it is very weird how it is currently written, with *such as* outside the brackets, and the tags in the brackets.

Comment: Note that the parentheses around tag names are cosmetic: most sites do not have them. There's no reasonable way for that sort of odd customization to be reflected in the generic watermark text, so your second suggestion would seem to be a non-starter.

Answer (score 6):

I somewhat agree with the premise of your post (an opening parenthese can be interpreted as being misplaced), but I don't agree with any of your suggestions.

The list of tags is clearly intended to look exactly the way one would type them in the tag box, so `(limits), (differential-equations), (real-analysis)` is wrong, as is a comma-separated list.

I don't see a problem with the current watermark text, but if it *had to* change, I'd suggest this:

> enter between 1 and 5 tags, such as 'limits differential-equations real-analysis'

This eliminates the parentheses, and thus the problem of its placement. The single quotes denote literal content, which was probably the intent of the original parens.